# Where clause for all items in list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have **SHIPMENT** Table like below.

> select ShipperNo,Parts from SHIPMENT

| ShipperNo | Parts |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | P1 |
| S1 | P2 |
| S1 | P3 |
| S1 | P4 |
| S2 | P1 |
| S2 | P2 |
| S3 | P1 |
| S4 | P2 |
| S4 | P3 |

I need to find all the Shippers that ship **ALL the parts** shipped by S2.

> select Parts from SHIPMENT where ShipperNo='S2'

would be

| Parts |
| --- |
| P1 |
| P2 |

I am not sure how to either do an intersection between the above two subqueries and get the ShipperNo.
I am not necessarily a DBA who  uses SQL on a day to day basis and this question stumped me in the interview, I am more of a Full stack Developer with basic SQL knowledge.

Edit1:I forgot to mention the interviewer asked me to do this without using the **count**.

Comment: I don't understand, you have the ShipperNo right there.

Comment: ^ same question... are you saying instead that you need to locate all other shippers that ship the same exact items that the shipper S2 ships?

Comment: I think you must have missed something in your description of the requirement or maybe its as simple as `select ShipperNo,Parts from SHIPMENT WHERE ShipperNo = 'S2'`

Comment: Yes, an alternate way to state the question is locate all other shippers that ship the same exact items that the shipper S2 ships.

Comment: @user2977259 `select ShipperNo,Parts from SHIPMENT where parts in (select Parts from SHIPMENT where ShipperNo='S2');`

Comment: @ErgestBasha It has to match **all the Parts**. , so this would not work.

Comment: @user2977259 can you edit the question and add your expected result based on the data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-`join` with a subquery:

Edit: solution without `count` function, per the details in the question:

```
with sub_s2(id, c) as (
   select s.shipperno, sum(s.shipperno != s1.shipperno and s1.shipperno = 'S2') from shipment s 
   join shipment s1 on s.parts = s1.parts 
   group by s.shipperno
)
select s.id shipperno from sub_s2 s where s.c = (select sum(s3.shipperno = 'S2') from shipment s3)
```

Output:

```
shipperno
---------
S1
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention they asked to do this without the count. I was able to do this with count as well. @Ajax1234

Comment: @user2977259 Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Count for each shipper the number of parts it has in commin with S2 and then filter on the ones who have exactly the same number of parts as S2:

```
select SH1.ShipperNo, count(*) partsCount
  from shipment SH1
 where SH1.Parts in (select SH2.Parts from SHIPMENT SH2 WHERE SH2.ShipperNo = 'S2')
 group by SH1.ShipperNo
having count(*) = (select count(*) from SHIPMENT SH3 WHERE SH3.ShipperNo = 'S2')
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the interviewer asked me to do this without the count. I was able to do this with count as well. Let me add this information to the question.